# To pass id from child popup window to parent window

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

In the below code ihave a parent window in which there is a dropdown and link button inside data grid.When i click the linkbutton a child popup window open in which i select a employee id and store in a hidden value and pass that id to parent window and bind in dropdown.But i can't able to pass value pls any one help me to solve the issue.

Parent

```
function ShowPopUp() { 
    var sFeatures = "dialogHeight: 400px;";           
    var myWindow = window.open("/Trans/Quote.aspx", "Quote", 
                               "width=900, height=200", sFeatures);
    window.document.getElementById("<%= btnHiddenForUpdate.ClientID%>").click();  
}
function setValue(myVal) {
    alert(myVal);
    document.getElementById("<%=ddlEMP.ClientID%>").value = myVal;
}
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEMP" runat="server" 
    CssClass="cbSupplierName" EnableViewState="True" Width="25%" >
</asp:DropDownList>


<ItemTemplate>                                              
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkQuote" runat="server" CommandName="Quote" Text="Quote" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

CodeBehind:

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowPopUp", "ShowPopUp()", true)`;

Child:

```
function updateParent() {
    var oVal = document.getElementById("<%=hid.ClientID%>").value;
    window.opener.setValue(oVal);
    window.close();
    return false;
}
<input type="hidden" id="hid" runat="server" />
```

Comment: did the `popup window` showing, did the `updateParent` working, and does it hit `setValue()`?

Comment: @Kyojimaru Yes it is holding the id but not passing value

Comment: by not passing value, did you mean `alert(myVal)` result in `null`, or it's not added to the `dropdownlist`

Comment: place an alert in updatePerent() and see what value you are getting in oVal variable. Also are you able to see the alert that you placed in setValue(myVal) function? if yes, then is it blank?

Comment: @Kyojimaru setValue function is not firing

Comment: @kaushalparik27 Yes i get the id but it is not passing the value.

Comment: when did you call the `updateParent()`, is it ever firing? place some alert before in the `updateParent()` like mentioned by @kaushal

Comment: @Kyojimaru Yes updateParent() is firing it holds the id

Comment: try commenting `window.document.getElementById("<%= btnHiddenForUpdate.ClientID%>").click();` out, did the `setValue()` firing after that?

Comment: @Kyojimaru No it is not firing

Answer (score 0):

I tried this minimal code to reproduce your issue, but seems working on my end.

Here is my Parent window:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowPopUp() {
            var sFeatures = "dialogHeight: 400px;";
            var myWindow = window.open("Default2.aspx", "Quote",
                                       "width=900, height=200", sFeatures);
        }
        function setValue(myVal) {
            alert(myVal);
            document.getElementById("<%=ddlEMP.ClientID%>").value = myVal;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEMP" runat="server"
                CssClass="cbSupplierName" EnableViewState="True" Width="25%">
                <asp:ListItem Text="testing1" Value="testing1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="testing" Value="testing" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

On code behind I am opening the page:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowPopUp", "ShowPopUp()", true);
}
```

and on child window:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateParent() {
            debugger;
            document.getElementById("<%=hid.ClientID%>").value = "testing";
            oVal = document.getElementById("<%=hid.ClientID%>").value;
            window.opener.setValue(oVal);
            window.close();
            return false;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClientClick="return updateParent()" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hid" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would suggest to write a minimal code and see what causes the issue at your end.
hope it helps./.